# Bundle file location to use that file or how to save in file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, bundling-and-minification

Where are the generated bundle files is placed in c# MVC?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Art")
       .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/", "*.js", true)
```

I was tried to find out in core but not able to get exact location . I want use that file for CDN purpose.

I am doing this because I don't want to minify each and every time and I will be able to change js css on server and bundle will automatically update version of file

Answer (score 0):

> Those files are created on the fly by the web server and cached in memory.

For additional info, you can read this article: [Where Did My ASP.NET Bundles Go in ASP.NET 5?](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/)